# Linkedin API show my own company page inside a iframe

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I have a linkedin company page associated to my linkedin account.

I created the associated verified App within Linkedin developers.

I'd want to show that company linkein page inside a iframe on my PHP website.

By showing a classic url like /in/companyName (or ID) it throws cross-origin error, so I'm trying using their API v2.

What I tried so far is:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/rest/profile/<company page id>
```

> error: {"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access
> token","status":401}

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/rest/organizations/<company page id>
```

> error: {"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access
> token","status":401}

the API documentation has no indications of how this URL can be structured adding the access token, I've found some tutorials of how to let users sign-in and then retrieve their own profile data, but I don't think is what I need here and looks a overkill for a simple case like mine, anyone had the same case before?

Comment: You'll probably want an _application authorization_ then, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-06#application-authorization=